# Can't get script to run using windows command line with batch file

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio

Environment is correct, but it's not finding my program.

Code for my python program, created using visual studio 2017, located here:
`C:\Users\Alex\Python Programs\pw\pw`.

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'f7nsdkfn2BDD3fkjTXjs6Fjsn',
             'blog': 'fdkNc32NskNskKslLI321n',
             'luggage': 12345}

import sys, pyperclip
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
  print("Usage: python pw.py [account] - copy account password")
sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1]      # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
  pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
  print("Password for " + account + " copied to clipboard")
else:
  print("There is no account named " + account)
```

I then created a .bat file located here: `C:\Users\Alex\Python Programs\pw\pw`

```
@py.exe C:\Users\Alex\Python Programs\pw\pw\pw.py %*
@pause
```

I know the environment is set correct as I get python details when typing python in the command line.

But if I type:

```
pw <luggage>
```

I get an error saying `The syntax of the command is incorrect`.

If I type:

```
python pw
```

I get this error `(null): can't open file 'pw': [Errno 2] No such file or directory`.

Not sure what I have done wrong and I have spent way too much time on this now.

I have now changed my batch file to runpw, when I double click this file I get this message:-
"'py.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: Does your batch file have the `.bat` extension? Is it on your `PATH`? Also, your path to the `pw.py` in the batch file should probably be quoted so that it's interpreted as a single argument instead of two.

Comment: The situation is arising because you have both a `pw.py` and a `pw.bat` file, so unless you explicitly specify the suffix Windows is confused about which one you mean. An alternative to doing that would be to give them different file names. e.g. Rename the batch file `runpw.bat` and use that to run it (with or without the suffix should work from the command-line).

Comment: I have renamed the batch file to runpw.bat but I keep getting the same error messages as what I put in the main body

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I reorganised my files and place them in this folder:-  C:\Users\Alex\Python_programs\Password_project

Having spaces in the file path originally may have been a cause of the issue.

Also make sure you do not save your files as pw.py.py lol

Comment: thats a workaround, not a fix ;) ...to fix it you just enclose paths always with doublequote like that: @py.exe "C:\Users\Alex\Python Programs\pw\pw\pw"

Comment: @Harry Thank you! Created my Windows username with a space and was facing problems while doing this exact same exercise. Enclose the path with double quote solved my problem.